# How to optimize query on normalized database structure?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to optimize a query that currently takes 0.00x s on a MySQL 5.x DB in order to retrieve data on a system without load.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   a.article_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(attr_f.attr_de) AS functions, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(attr_n.attr_de) AS miscellaneous
FROM `articles_test` a
LEFT JOIN articles_attr AS f ON a.article_id = f.article_id AND f.attr_group_id = 26
LEFT JOIN articles_attr AS attr ON a.article_id = attr.article_id AND attr.attr_group_id = 27
LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS attr_f ON attr_f.attr_id = f.attr_id
LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS attr_n ON attr_n.attr_id = attr.attr_id
WHERE a.article_id = 11
```

EXPLAIN returns

```
1   SIMPLE  a   
    NULL
    const   article_id  article_id  3   const   1   100.00  
    NULL

1   SIMPLE  f   
    NULL
    ref article_id_2,article_id article_id_2    6   const,const 2   100.00  Using index 
1   SIMPLE  attr    
    NULL
    ref article_id_2,article_id article_id_2    6   const,const 4   100.00  Using index 
1   SIMPLE  attr_f  
    NULL
    ref attr_id attr_id 3   test.f.attr_id  1   100.00  
    NULL

1   SIMPLE  attr_n  
    NULL
    ref attr_id attr_id 3   test.attr.attr_id   1   100.00  
    NULL
```

There are indexes on all fields that are queried. Is there another way to retrieve the data with a simpler and faster query?

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_attr` (
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `article_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `attr_group_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
 `attr_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `article_id_2` (`article_id`,`attr_group_id`,`attr_id`),
 KEY `article_id` (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 

CREATE TABLE `cat_attr` (
 `attr_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `attr_group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `sort` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `attr_de` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `attr_id` (`attr_id`,`attr_group_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `attr_group_id` (`attr_group_id`,`attr_de`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=380 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `articles_test` (
 `article_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 UNIQUE KEY `article_id` (`article_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=221614 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Table articles_attr contains about 0.5 million rows.

Comment: What is the point with aggregating and doing group by on `a.article_id` when you have a WHERE clause selecting only one `a.article_id`?

Comment: Good point, this is a left over from performing this query to get all articles. I removed it, but the performance stays almost identical with 0.009s

Comment: You should also remove GROUP_CONCAT then since it's an aggregating function

Comment: well this one needs to stay ;-) each article might have multiple functions. Removeing group_comcat (or replacing by comcat) will not retrieve the desired resultset.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help you. In particular, we need to know exactly what indexes you have created, and your table definitions.  Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 and pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Thank you @O.Jones for the input. I have edited the question accoringly.

Comment: Is it really important to have the `group_concat` instead of having the individual attributes in separate rows? What is the application layer you are using to process the output of this query?

Comment: @merlin . . . 0.009 seconds seems short enough.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `WHERE` clause specifies the value of `article_id`, there is no real need to let the `select` clause return it. It is better to remove it, also because it does not comply with SQL standards that say that if you have an aggregation (`group_concat`) all non-aggregating expressions in the `select` clause must be in the `group by` clause. But doing that (as in your question's first version) would give some overhead. So better remove it.

As the `WHERE` condition is on the primary key and you don't need any data from the `articles_test` table, you could omit the `articles_test` table, and put the `WHERE` condition on the foreign keys instead.

Finally, there is a kind of Cartesian join, as you combine every hit in `attr_f` with every hit in `attr_n`. This could lead to some duplicates in the `group_concat` outputs and represents a performance hit.

If it is OK to have such duplicates removed, then maybe you would have a better performance by splitting the query into to groups: one for the *function* output, one for the *miscellaneous* output. The group is then formed by `attr_group_id`.

This will also allow for turning the outer joins into inner joins.

So the output would be the unpivoted version of what you were after:

```
SELECT     attr.attr_group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cat.attr_de) AS functions
FROM       articles_attr AS attr 
INNER JOIN cat_attr AS cat ON cat.attr_id = attr.attr_id
WHERE      attr.article_id = 11
       AND attr.attr_group_id IN (26, 27) 
GROUP BY   attr.attr_group_id
```

So now the output will have two rows. The one with 26 in the first column will list the functions in the second column, and the one with 27 in the first column will list the miscellaneous.

True, the output format is different, but I think you will be able to rework the code that uses this query, while benefiting from the performance increase (which I expect).

If you need the pivoted version, then use a `case when` expression:

```
SELECT     GROUP_CONCAT(CASE attr.attr_group_id WHEN 26 THEN cat.attr_de END) AS functions,
           GROUP_CONCAT(CASE attr.attr_group_id WHEN 27 THEN cat.attr_de END) AS miscellaneous
FROM       articles_attr AS attr 
INNER JOIN cat_attr AS cat ON cat.attr_id = attr.attr_id
WHERE      attr.article_id = 11
       AND attr.attr_group_id IN (26, 27)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and shafed of some ms. Now under 0.006.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 9ms for a query like this isn't bad. There's no radical improvement to be had. You may be able to squeeze another millisecond or two from the query, and you may not.

Your three-column index on `articles_attr` looks OK. You might try switching the order of the first two columns in the index to see if you get better performance.

As it is, your single-column index on that table is unnecessary: that indexing functionality is provided because the same column comes first in your three-column index. Dropping that index probably won't help your query performance, but it will help insert performance.

`GROUP_CONCAT()` makes sense here. It's perfectly valid to aggregate an entire result set. You might add `GROUP BY a.article_id` just for clarity; it won't make any performance difference because you already choose only a single value of that column.

On `cat_attr`, a compound index on `(attr_id, attr_de)` may help. But that's apparently a small table, so it won't help too much.

Do you need the `LEFT JOIN` operations to join `articles_attr` to `cat_attr`? Or, by the structure of your data, is every value of `articles_attr.attr_id` guaranteed to find a match in `cat_attr.attr_id`.  If you can change those `LEFT JOIN` operations to `JOIN`s you may get a slight speedup.

Answer (score 0):

```
`attr_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

Why `NULL`?  Don't you always need an attr?  The reason I am bringing this up is that you do not have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY` on `articles_attr`.  The `NULL` prevents promoting the `UNIQUE` key to PK.  Change to `NOT NULL` and promote the `UNIQUE` to PK.

```
KEY `article_id` (`article_id`)
```

Redundant, Drop it.

The structure of the many:many tables is sub-optimal.  Several tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

If you don't need "many:many", switch to "1:many"; it is more efficient.

You can probably use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` since you need to get all the way to `attr_f` and `attr_n`.

Moving the Joins for the Group_concats into the `SELECT` *may* help:

```
SELECT  a.article_id, 
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(ca.attr_de)
            FROM  articles_attr AS aa
            JOIN  cat_attr AS ca USING(attr_id)
            WHERE  aa.attr_group_id = 26
              AND  aa.article_id = a.article_id
        ) AS functions, 
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(attr_f.attr_de)
            FROM  ..
            JOIN  ..
            WHERE  .. 
        ) AS miscellaneous
    FROM  `articles_test` a
    WHERE  a.article_id = 11
```

But perhaps the most important is to avoid making the already-bad EAV schema design worse by normalizing the attributes!.  That is, get rid of the table `cat_attr`, and move `attr_de` into `articles_attr`.  This will cut in half the number of `JOINs`.

Comment: What do you mean by already-bad EAV? I can still change it as I am designing the schema right now. The table cat_attr holds the names of the attributes. E.g. group_id = 12 (color) 41=red. That way I can just write 41 and article_id to table articles_attr and I know that this article is red. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You have seen the tip of the iceberg.  I added the tag `[entity-attribute-value]`; follow it to read other horror stories.  My blog is [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)